# The type or namespace 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' - Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions

I've just installed Visual Studio 2022 and I'm attempting to develop a BlobTrigger Azure function. As part of the default class that is created, the following namespaces are included:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```

However, red lines appear under each of these with the message:

```
The type or namespace 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'
```

Any ideas on what I might need to install to get this working?

Comment: run the installer again (you should have a Visual Studio Installer app) and install the azure components

Comment: The Azure Development option has been selected and is showing as installed in the Visual Studio Installer app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496158/the-type-or-namespace-name-azure-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsoft)

Comment: @peterbonar Do you have these packages `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs`, `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` installed in your visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The type or namespace 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'.

You should have the packages installed in your visual studio to use them in your application.

- To install these packages, go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console, run the below given commands.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
```

[image]

Or To install packages directly:
Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage Nuget Packages for Solution.

[image]

---

***I have created a sample Blob Trigger Azure function.***

I have reproduced the issue by removing the packages installed in my environment and I was getting the same error.

[image]

After installing the below packages in application, I could fix the error and able to get the expected results.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

[image]